# Can't use a library installed with VCPKG in CLion

Tags: cmake, clion, vcpkg, openmesh

I followed the tutorial described in the VCPKG [github site](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/docs/examples/installing-and-using-packages.md)  and then installed OpenMesh 8.0, and after, i linked the toolchain

```
-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/diolante/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake
```

in Clion toolchain settings and when I reload the `CMakeLists.txt` that I changed in the Clion project:

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(lul)

find_package(openmesh REQUIRED)

add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main openmesh)
```

The following error returns at Clion output:

```
CMake Error at /home/diolante/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:288 (_find_package):   By not providing "Findopenmesh.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has   asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "openmesh",   but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "openmesh" with any
  of the following names:

    openmeshConfig.cmake
    openmesh-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "openmesh" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "openmesh_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files. If
  "openmesh" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
```

Answer (score 7):

The following is based on Visual Studio compilers but should be easily adoptable to different environments.

First you need to install the triplet you are going to use, e.g.

```
vcpkg install openmesh --triplet x64-windows --triplet x86-windows
```

(If you are not sure whether to build your project x64 or x86 simply install both triplets.)

Select the proper toolchain in the "Toolchains" entry under "Build, Execution, Deployment". To make a toolchain default move it to the first entry in the list by using the small up and down arrows.

[image: Toolchain Selection]

Select the toolchain in the "CMake" entry under "Build, Execution, Deployment"

[image: ToolchainSelection2]

If you selected a toolchain/architecture for which the OpenMesh triplet has not been installed you will see exactly the error you are experiencing.

`vcpkg` provides two variables for `OpenMesh` 8.1 that need to be used to specify the include directories and the libraries to link with as follows:

```
target_include_directories(main PRIVATE ${OPENMESH_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE ${OPENMESH_LIBRARIES})
```

The entire `CMakeLists.txt` for this project now would look like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(lul)

find_package(openmesh REQUIRED)

add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_include_directories(main PRIVATE ${OPENMESH_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE ${OPENMESH_LIBRARIES})
# the following line is only needed for Visual Studio compilers
target_compile_definitions(main PRIVATE -D_USE_MATH_DEFINES)
```

The sample project can be downloaded from [here](https://github.com/VolkerEnderlein/SampleCLionProject.git)

Comment: Could you help to upload a working example Clion project to github? Whatever vcpkg library is fine.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a CLion installed, so I cannot  help with this. But the reason is in the CMakeLists.txt not in the CLion project I think.

Comment: @Justalearner Just installed CLion and checked the steps. The issue seems to be most likely related to a missing OpenMesh vcpkg triplet. Will upload project tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you for the demo project! @vre

Comment: +1 for the fix, and a note to CLion users: by default CLion uses Visual Studio as a Toolchain, but the "Architecture" dropdown menu is empty. If it's empty, it'll default to x86 architecture, so be sure to explicitly choose x64 if you're working on an x64 project!